# Modifying X-frame-options in a Django app deployed using Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, http-headers, x-frame-options

I'm trying to embed an iframe on my portfolio page of a django app that I deployed on heroku. After doing some reading, apparently, I have to modify this property called X-frame-options in my HTTP headers, but I'm not sure where I'm supposed to find it in my Django or Heroku files/dashboards and what I'm supposed to set it to if I want to allow it to be embedded on an external website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to set this property in your settings.py:

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SOME_DOMAIN_LOADING_THE_IFRAME'
```